# Is the value of probability of X belonging to a set 0 for a continuous random variable distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with a PDF of the form

$$
f_{X}(x)= \begin{cases}c(1-x) & \text { if } x \in[0,1] \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$

If $A= \{ (1/k): k \text{ is an integer}, k≥2\}$, then $Pr(X∈A)=$

Here, is $Pr(X∈A)= 0$? Because a continuous random variable has value $0$ at a point and a set can be thought of as having several points.

Or, is $Pr(X∈A)= 3/4$? Because $A$ is the set from a little over $0$ to $1/2$, and the value of $Pr (X≤1/2) = 3/4$ after integrating (But $Pr(X≤1/2) $includes $0$ and set $A$ doesn't so this is probably wrong)
​

Please help.
​

Comment: $Pr (X \in A)= \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} Pr(X=\frac  1 k)=0$.

Comment: Can you Post rhe exercise Word by word?

Answer (score 1):

If a random variable has an absolutely continous distribution, that is, for every measurable set $A$ then $\mathbb P(X\in\mathcal A)=0$ measurable set $A$, since for any measurable set $A$, the probability
$$
\mathbb P(X\in A) = \int_A f(x)\ \mathsf dx
$$
where $f$ is a probability density for $X$, and of course the Lebesgue integral over a set of measure zero is zero.